# Retrieve list of indexes in an Access database

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I know there's a way to get a list of all tables in an Access database by using the quering the MsysObjects:

```
SELECT MSysObjects.Name FROM MsysObjects
WHERE
  Left$([Name],1)<>'~' AND
  Left$([Name],4)<>'Msys' AND
  MSysObjects.Type=1
```

Does anybody know a similar (or other) way to retrieve a list of all indexes in an MS-Access database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can examine `TableDef` objects to access the index names.

```vb
Public Sub ShowIndexNames()
    Dim tdf As TableDef
    Dim idx As Index
    Dim num_indexes As Long

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    For Each tdf In CurrentDb.TableDefs
        num_indexes = tdf.Indexes.Count
        If Left$(tdf.Name, 4) <> "MSys" Then
            If num_indexes > 0 Then
                For Each idx In tdf.Indexes
                    Debug.Print tdf.Name, idx.Name
                Next idx
            End If
         End If
    Next tdf

ExitHere:
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    Select Case Err.Number
    Case 3110
        'Could not read definitions; no read definitions '
        'permission for table or query '<Name>'. '
        Debug.Print "No read definitions permission for " _
            & tdf.Name
        num_indexes = 0
        Resume Next
    Case Else
        Debug.Print Err.Number & "-> " & Err.Description
        GoTo ExitHere
    End Select
End Sub
```

**Edit**: Revised the sub to ignore MSys* (Access system) tables.

You could also use ADO's `OpenSchema` method to retrieve information about indexes.  The code below lists the index name, associated table, and whether the index is the primary key.  I wrote it to use late binding for ADO because that doesn't require setting the reference for *Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects [version] Library*.

```vb
Const adSchemaIndexes As Long = 12
Dim cn As Object ' ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As Object ' ADODB.Recordset
Dim i As Long

Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection
Set rs = cn.OpenSchema(adSchemaIndexes)
With rs
    ' enable next three lines to view all the recordset column names
'    For i = 0 To (.Fields.Count - 1)
'        Debug.Print .Fields(i).Name
'    Next i
    Do While Not .EOF
       Debug.Print !TABLE_NAME, !INDEX_NAME, !PRIMARY_KEY
       .MoveNext
    Loop
    .Close
End With
Set rs = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing
```

If you prefer to examine indexes for a single table rather than for every table in the db, pass the table name as the fifth element of an array.

```vb
Set rs = cn.OpenSchema(adSchemaIndexes, Array(Empty, Empty, Empty, Empty, "tblFoo"))
```

Answer (score 5):

If you need to use .Net OleDb provider and nothing more you can use

```
DataTable indexes = 
(myOleDbConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbSchemaGuid.Indexes,
new object[] { null, null, null, null, tableName});
```

(specifing the right connection and the right table).

In the indexes DataTable you have indexes and fields all toghether.

Answer (score 5):

Augmentation to [HansUp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2537468/4228193).

In addition to knowing the names of indexes it's almost always essential to know which fields are referenced in those indexes. For example, when importing tables from an access DB to SQL Server 2008 R2, it doesn't copy keys and indices, so I need to regenerate them.  Thusfar this script doesn't properly handle foreign key constraints, but should generate primary keys as well as standard indexes.

```vb
Public Sub Generate_tSQLIndex()
    Dim tdf As TableDef
    Dim fld As DAO.Field
    Dim idx As Index
    Dim num_indexes As Long
    Dim indexdef_tsql As String
    Dim pk As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    For Each tdf In CurrentDb.TableDefs
        num_indexes = tdf.Indexes.Count
        If Left$(tdf.Name, 4) <> "MSys" Then
            If num_indexes > 0 Then
                For Each idx In tdf.Indexes
                    pk = idx.Primary
                    If pk Then indexdef_tsql = "ALTER TABLE [" + tdf.Name + "] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_" + tdf.Name + "_" + idx.Name + "] PRIMARY KEY " Else indexdef_tsql = "CREATE "
                    If idx.Unique And Not pk Then indexdef_tsql = indexdef_tsql + "UNIQUE "
                    If idx.Clustered Then indexdef_tsql = indexdef_tsql + "CLUSTERED " Else indexdef_tsql = indexdef_tsql + "NONCLUSTERED "
                    If Not pk Then indexdef_tsql = indexdef_tsql + "INDEX [" + idx.Name + "] ON [" + tdf.Name + "] "
                    indexdef_tsql = indexdef_tsql + "("
                    For Each fld In idx.Fields
                        indexdef_tsql = indexdef_tsql + "[" + fld.Name + "]"
                        If fld.Attributes = 1 Then indexdef_tsql = indexdef_tsql + " DESC, " Else indexdef_tsql = indexdef_tsql + " ASC, "
                    Next fld
                    If idx.Fields.Count > 0 Then indexdef_tsql = Left(indexdef_tsql, Len(indexdef_tsql) - 2)
                    indexdef_tsql = indexdef_tsql + ")"
                    Debug.Print indexdef_tsql
                Next idx
            End If
         End If
    Next tdf

ExitHere:
        Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 3110
        'Could not read definitions; no read definitions '
        'permission for table or query '<Name>'. '
        Debug.Print "No read definitions permission for " + tdf.Name
        num_indexes = 0
        Resume Next
    Case Else
        Debug.Print Err.Number & "-> " & Err.Description
        GoTo ExitHere
    End Select
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Very useful. You need to add an extra row 
Dim fld As DAO.Field

Answer (score -1):

It appears this can be done with either:

```
SELECT
     szRelationship as [IndexName]
FROM MSysRelationships
ORDER BY szRelationship ASC
```

Or

```
SELECT
     Name as [IndexName]
FROM MSysObjects
WHERE Type = 8
ORDER BY Name ASC
```

***Note:***  Type 8 appears to be reserved, and is not listed as the other types are (Tables_Local = 1; Tables_Linked_ODBC = 4; Tables_Linked = 6; Queries = 5; Forms = -32768; Reports = -32764; Macros = -32766; Modules = -32761)

Reference:

- https://www.opengatesw.net/ms-access-tutorials/Access-Articles/Microsoft-Access-System-Tables.htm