# Retrieve list of forms in an Access database

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

How can I retrieve a list of all forms in a MS-Access database?

To retrieve a list of all tables I use this:

```
For Each TDef In CurrentDb.TableDefs
    If Left(TDef.Name, 4) <> "MSys" And Left(TDef.Name, 7) <> "~TMPCLP" Then
        Debug.Print TDef.Name
    End If
Next
```

Also see [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536955/retrieve-list-of-indexes-in-an-access-database).

But I can't do this for forms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use AllForms for a list of names. These are not instances of forms, just names.

```
Sub ListForms()
Dim frm As Object
Dim LiveForm As Form

    For Each frm In CurrentProject.AllForms
        Debug.Print frm.Name
        ''To use the form, uncomment
        ''DoCmd.OpenForm frm.Name, acViewDesign
        ''Set LiveForm = Forms(frm.Name)
        ''Do not forget to close when you are done
        ''DoCmd.Close acForm, frm.Name
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I have to use `Dim frm As AccessObject` to make it run

Comment: And how can I retrieve the title of the Form? `Debug.Print frm.Properties("Caption")` doesn't work

Comment: You must first open the form to get additional details. AllForms is more or less a list and all you can get is (more or less) the name, creation date and whether it is loaded or not.